# Qual configuração deve ser feita no Angular para uso com Jekyll?

Tags: angular, jekyll

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que usará o Jekyll com seus temas como base do site, porém, preciso criar um layout do jekyll `<jekyll_root>/_layout/angular.html` que será carregado para as páginas que usam o Angular, conforme a respectiva diretiva.

Sendo assim preciso que ao invés do Angular ao construir a aplicação (ng build) gere o arquivo `index.html` conforme o padrão e os arquivos `js`, ele gere um arquivo na pasta `<jekyll_root>/_layout` com o nome `angular.html`, já os arquivos JavaScript (js) devem ser gravados na pasta `<jekyll_root>/assets/js/angular`.

Os demais arquivos devem ser copiados para pastas respectivas, como "images" para `<jekyll_root>/asset/images`, "css" para pasta `<jekyll_root>/asset/css`, etc.

Quais as configurações devem ser feitas no Angular para este comportamento?

Comment: O projeto e seu código está sendo publicado no github em https:/github.com/StreetPet, o projeto é opensource e openhardware.

Comment: Vc precisa MESMO usar o Jekyll e angular? Um dos problemas que vc vai enfrentar é que os dois usam chaves nos templates, sendo assim, o Jekyll vai remover coisas como `{{exemplo}}`. Para que os 2 funcionem juntos será necessário alterar todas as tags de angular para diferenciá-las das tags do Jekyll.

Comment: Realmente isso pode vir a atrapalhar, mesmo, mas no estágio que estou basta que eu consiga gerar um novo layout par ao Jekyll, ou seja gravar o html na pasta `_layout` e os scripts na pasta `js/angular` conforme o projeto de app, já que cada app vai gerar um layout.

Comment: No momento estou copiando tudo para uma pasta dentro de `_site` e fazendo o deploy no servidor,

Answer (score 0):

Eu encontrei a seguinte solução.

Criei um **workspace do angular** com o comando `ng new --skip-tests --skip-install  Jekyll --directory . --defaults` no próprio diretório de trabalho do Jakyll, então editei o arquivo `angular.json` e alterei as seguintes propriedades:.

```
"aot": true,
"optimization": true,
"sourceMap": false,
"buildOptimizer": true,
"outputPath": "app/voluntarios",
"baseHref": "/app/voluntarios/",
```

Em especial `outputPath` que apontei para o diretório onde ficará os arquivos compilados do angular dentro do Jekyll antes do build dele. Alterei a diretiva `baseHref` para apontar a URL base que será o resultado final depois do build do Jekyll.

Também ajustei as seguintes propriedades, com relação a pasta onde está meu projeto do Angular:

```
"index": "../Angular/projects/JekyllFirebaseVoluntarios/src/index.html",
"main": "../Angular/projects/JekyllFirebaseVoluntarios/src/main.ts",
"polyfills": "../Angular/projects/JekyllFirebaseVoluntarios/src/polyfills.ts",
"tsConfig": "../Angular/projects/JekyllFirebaseVoluntarios/tsconfig.app.json",
"assets": [""],
"styles": [""],
"scripts": [""]
```

Então apontei cada uma para a pasta onde está o projeto que resultará nos arquivos usados pelo Jakyll.

Finalmente executo o Jekyll e deixo ele monitorando as alterações e continuo meu trabalho com angular em outro terminal, onde deixo o angular também monitorando as alterações, mas não com o comando `ng server`, mas sim com `ng build`, veja que tanto o comando do Jekyll como do Angular são executados na pasta de trabalho do angular.